# Как вывести запись WHERE id IN с повторениями?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть строка

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id in (1,1,1,2,2,2)  ");
```

По итогу она выдаст результат в две строки под `ID1` и `ID2` как сделать так, что бы выводился результат со всеми повторениями ?  `ID1 ID1 ID1 ID2 ID2 ID2`

phpMyAdmin 5.1.0 Версия сервера баз данных: 5.7.27-30

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120412/discussion-on-question-by-----where-id-in--).

Answer (score -1):

Нужно принудительно сделать столько SELECT'ов, сколько строк вам нужно. Их можно объединить в один запрос при помощи UNION ALL

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = ID1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = ID2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = ID3
...
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = IDN
```

Comment: Это очень плохое, неэффективное решение поставленной задачи. Нужно стараться мыслить шире, не пытаться решить задачу в лоб, а сначала понять, какой результат нужно получить, а потом уже думать над решением.

Comment: @Ипатьев, критикуешь — предлагай

Comment: Можно создать временную таблицу с значения перечисленными в IN и потом сделать с этой таблицей LEFT JOIN

Comment: Как это применить тут `$res = file_get_contents("https://ads.pontogram.com/restid.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id IN ($res)  ");` У меня выдает ошибку предложенное решение.

Comment: @Илья, Вам в любом случае придется писать цикл по списку внутри `$res` и либо генерировать запрос, собирая несколько SELECT через UNION либо для каждого (каждого уникального) выполнять отдельный SELECT. Вставлять напрямую строку из внешнего источника в запрос - это плохая затея.